# Empty cells become "" when converting CSV to JSON - Python

Tags: python, json, csv, null

Currently I am using the code below to convert a CSV into JSON. The problem is, that the return puts empty strings for values that are empty in the CSV. I need these to be null in order for api calls to work.

How can I get null for values that are blank in the CSV?

```
def csvToJson(tokenHeader):
    data = []
    with open('CSV/quiz-questions.csv') as questionFile:
        csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(questionFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in csvReader:
            data.append(row)

    with open('JSON/questions.json', 'w+') as jsonFile:
        jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert all the empty strings to `None` before appending to the list.

```
for row in csvReader:
    row = {key: (None if value == "" else value) for key, value in row.items()}
    data.append(row)
```

Python `None` is translated to JSON `null`.

BTW, you can use `json.dump(jsonFile, data, indent=4)` rather than calling `jsonFile.write()` and `json.dumps()` separately.

Comment: This approach makes sense to me, but the syntax isn't working.

Comment: I had a typo in the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Very cool solution and bonus information. Thanks for your help!